# Setting Maven params in Jenkins

Tags: maven, parameters, build, jenkins

I am experimenting the Jenkins, and am looking for a way to allow Jenkins to set parameters for different project builds. Normally all these attributes are stored in the settings.xml (I currently have a settings.xml for the user running Jenkins which includes default properties and my repositories).

I want to have different builds of the same project that specific different Maven parameters and also different goals. (have a job that runs compile checks frequently, another that deploys the app to the test server every hour, another for releasing to staging and then prod)

What is the best way for creating parameterized builds in Jenkins?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are some options for you. Here's what I'm using:

#### Create profiles in your build.

```
<profile>
    <activation>
        <file>
            <exists>findbugs-exclude.xml</exists>
        </file>
    </activation>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludeFilterFile>findbugs-exclude.xml</excludeFilterFile>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
<profile>
    <id>package</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                            <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

The you can define in jenkins `clean install -P package` - for package task or `clean install` for normal build

#### Put parameters directly to pom from command line:

Maven call:

```
mvn clean install -Dparameter.one=ONE -Dparameter.two=TWO
```

POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>test</name>
    <properties>
        <testng.version>6.4</testng.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>${testng.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

If you run it normally testng version 6.4 will be used. But if you run it like:
`mvn clean install -Dtestng.version=6.3.1` testng version 6.3.1 will be used.

See

> Downloading:
>   http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/testng/testng/6.3.1/testng-6.3.1.pom
>   Downloaded:
>   http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/testng/testng/6.3.1/testng-6.3.1.pom
>   (0 B at 0.0 KB/sec) Downloading:
>   http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/testng/testng/6.3.1/testng-6.3.1.jar
>   Downloaded:
>   http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/testng/testng/6.3.1/testng-6.3.1.jar
>   (0 B at 0.0 KB/sec)

You can parametrize default part of pom (setting default values directly and overriding it by execution properties)

#### Finally you can use environment variables [Parameterized Build](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build) or [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin)

Change in last example version:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>${env.testngVersion}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

In bash you can call:

```
export testngVersion=6.0
mvn clean install
```

Or in jenkins by setting testngVersion=6.0 in `This build is parameterized` section

Comment: One important thing to note is that it seems that Jenkins build props are ignored in the Maven build task in a freeform job (Maven 2/3 jobs work fine).