# How to make parameters dependent maven build?

Tags: maven, maven-3

How can i make maven build dependent on parameters? I want to do some changes to configuration files when building project for clustered environment. So if usual build is something like ***mvn clean package*** then when building for cluster i want to run smth like ***mvn clean package cluster*** and make configuration changes in this case. Btw, my main pom.xml consists of just several included modules to which i need to pass this parameter so consider this as well.

Comment: What do you mean by included modules and parameter passing to those modules ?

Comment: looks a bit like a task for profiles - http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

Comment: See my answer: [How to get a command-line property to overwrite a maven property](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13709976/651140)

Comment: Yeap, i did it with profiles. Thanks SpaceTrucker!