# Override Maven property in dependency pom

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

I am trying to build a project with a dependency like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.foo.bar</groupId>
    <artifactId>packageA</artifactId>
    <version>${branch}-3.2.4.25.2</version>
</dependency>
```

The pom for com.foo.bar.packageA has a dependency like this:

```
<properties>
    <branch>DEV</branch> <!-- default value -->
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.baz</groupId>
        <artifactId>packageB</artifactId>
        <version>${branch}-3.2.4.25.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I build with the command:

```
mvn clean install -Dbranch=Iago
```

The dependency for com.foo.bar.packageA is resolved as I expect: Iago-3.2.4.25.2. However, the dependency for org.baz.packageB is resolved as: DEV-3.2.4.25.2. Am I not correct in thinking that the branch property with value DEV should be overridden with my command-line value of Iago?

Comment: I don't think you can overridden property of dependency pom. see this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13708738/how-to-get-a-command-line-property-to-overwrite-a-maven-property

Comment: Hey thanks, this seems to be the case. If you make it the answer I'll accept it.