# How to use maven run parameters in the maven project?

Tags: maven, command-line

I am having a new Maven project and I want to pass parameters through command line..

This is my requirement -

If I pass - `install -Dinfra=local` then my test should run on local machine

If I pass - `install -Dinfra=ip` then my test should run on the machine having desired ip.

I just wanted to know how to configure this **`infra`** into my project so that I can access that through command line.. Many thanks!

Comment: Do you need to access the parameter from your code? If so, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500533/access-maven-properties-defined-in-the-pom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a property in your POM:

```
<project>
    ...
    <properties>
         <infra>local</infra>
    </properties>
    ...
</project>
```

Then you can reference it in the POM by using `${infra}`. You can overwrite the value of the property through the command line (as in your example).

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13709976/927493