# Transitive maven plugin dependency configuration

Tags: maven

If I have two maven plugins, where `A` depends on `B` and `B` has configuration parameters, how and where should I define configuration for `B`?

I could think of three solutions, which of one I know is not applicable, and I'm not sure which one works, or there are any more possiblities. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any example even for this simple case.

**Try 1** (not possible)

Put `<configuration>` under dependencies. This is not possible as a `<dependency>` tag cannot contain a `<configuration>` tag ([see xsd](https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd)).

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>A</groupId>
    <artifactId>A</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>B</groupId>
            <artifactId>B</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <paramForB><param>bbb</param></paramForB>
            </configuration>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

**Try 2**

Put the configuration parameter under the config of `A`.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>A</groupId>
    <artifactId>A</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>B</groupId>
            <artifactId>B</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
        <paramForB><param>bbb</param></paramForB>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**Try 3**

Introduce `B` as a separate plugin with the configuration I need.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>B</groupId>
    <artifactId>B</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <paramForB><param>bbb</param></paramForB>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>A</groupId>
    <artifactId>A</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>B</groupId>
            <artifactId>B</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

**Further questions** (just curious)

1. Also, what if `B` depends on `C`. How should I configure `C`?
2. And if I have a maven plugin `X` which also depends on `B` but would use it with other configuration: can I do that?

Comment: If you have two plugins they can't depend on each other...Furthermore the dependencies of a plugin is something different...and you can only give configurations to plugins but not to dependencies. Maybe you can make a more concrete example what you are trying to accomplish....

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I've read more about the topic and found my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is basically **Try 2**, i.e., add configurations of `B` to the plugin usage `A`, but it depends on how plugin `A` was implemented as it its responsibility to pass the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

In maven you have profiles and properties.
First start with properties:

*Project B*

```
<properties>
   <customeParameter>parameterInB</customeParameter>
</properties>
<plugin>
    <groupId>A</groupId>
    <artifactId>A</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>B</groupId>
            <artifactId>B</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <paramForB>${customeParameter}</paramForB>
            </configuration>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

*Project A*

```
<properties>
   <customeParameter>overrideInA</customeParameter>
</properties>
```

See my answer to question: [How to get a command-line property to overwrite a maven property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13709976/651140)

My example will work if project B is a parent for project A. If not, please define share configuration in parent pom (which will be parent for A and B) and parametrize it. Then in child you can define in "properties" section values for this configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I didn't know that only properties can be overriden in command line.
Maven says, I cannot define the <configuration> tag under a <dependency> tag, I have already tried that.
In the meantime, I got a deeper understanding how the maven plugins work so I posted the answer, I was looking for.