# Making maven do file copying between building and running

Tags: maven

**Revised Question** (old question below):

Problem: When building and running a Jenkins plugin project in NetBeans using Maven, Java class loader *used by log4j* does not find some files (like configuration file, a custom appender, JDBC driver). They need to be copied to another location under `target`, and then they are found.

The solution I think I want is this: **I want to give maven an extra command line argument(s)**, configured in NetBeans. **This should make maven do extra step after building and before running anything**. The step can either be the file copying (specified in pom.xml or by the command arguments), or it can be running a script (specified in pom.xml or by the command line arguments).

What to add to pom.xml?  Some maven plugin?

---

**Old Question** (for reference)

I have a maven project for "my-jenkins-plugin". I need to use *log4j* with it. I currently have *log4j.xml* at this path:

```
./src/main/resources/log4j.xml
```

When I do clean&build in Netbeans, it gets copied to these places:

```
./target/classes/log4j.xml
./target/generated-classes/emma/classes/log4j.xml
./target/my-jenkins-plugin/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.xml
```

However, log4j does not find the file from any of these locations. I need to manually copy it to this location:

```
./target/work/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.xml
```

And then it works as expected.

More details: Maven 2, Netbeans 7.2. It's standard Jenkins plugin, project originally created with `mvn hpi:create`, and Netbeans uses Jetty to run Jenkins. Classpath used when running under NetBeans is `java.class.path=C:\work\maven\boot\classworlds-1.1.jar` (which is an existing jar) and I haven't found a way to add anything to this classpath, but if I add *log4j.xml* to root of that jar file, it is also found and works (obviously this is not a satisfactory solution). I know if log4j works or not simply by looking at console output, either it's correct log lines, or the dreaded `log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (TestLog). log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.` error and nothing else.

**Question**: How can I have either

- the *log4j.xml* found in the first set of locations,
- or *log4j.xml* found in a location outside *target* dir, like *C:\log4j\log4j.xml*
- or make maven and/or netbeans to copy *log4j.xml* to a location where it is found now
- or any other nice way to let me give my plugin *log4j.xml* after clean&build automatically, when debugging with NB?

Comment: A workaround I'm now using, is adding normal Java properties for a source and a destination file, and if these are present, the file is copied in `static{}` block before getting the instance of Logger. As long as this is the first `Logger.getLogger` call, the file copy is done before log4j reads the XML, and all works. But this is hardly a good solution, this is not an ideal place for such a copy...

Comment: @JohnYeary Do you have a reason to think this is maven-2 specific?

Comment: I was just going through a number of the NetBeans issues, and doing triage. I noted that you made specific mention of Maven 2, so I added an additional tag.

Comment: Disclaimer: I have never developed a Jenkins plugin so forgive me if I am totally out of context. From the example you give it looks Jenkins assumes the plugin to be a WAR artifact. Did you try to use a war packaging instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I got maven to copy .class and .jar files to new location before executing `hpi:run` goal. The `log4j.xml` is still copied in my Java code in a `static{}` block before instantiating log4j. To use this profile, I added `-P netbeans` to maven command line args in Netbeans:

Profile and plugin definition in `pom.xml`:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>netbeans</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>                
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>copy</id>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <target>
                                    <ant antfile="${basedir}/log4j/ant.xml">
                                        <target name="log4jcopy"/>
                                    </ant>
                                </target>
                            </configuration>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal> <!-- means antrun:run -->
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Build XML for ant, `log4j/ant.xml`:

```
<project default="log4jcopy">
    <target name="log4jcopy">
        <echo message="Copying class files so that log4j finds them at runtime."/>
        <copy verbose="true"
              todir="target/work/webapp/WEB-INF/lib">
            <fileset
                dir="log4j"
                includes="mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar" />
        </copy>
        <copy verbose="true"
              todir="target/work/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/hyde/jenkins/myplugin">
            <fileset
                dir="target/classes/hyde/jenkins/plugins/myplugin"
                includes="LogAppender*.class" />
        </copy>
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using the ant copy plugin using your snippet.

Answer (score 12):

You could use the [Maven Ant plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) to run an Ant script that did the copying, or use the [Maven resources plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/), which seems aimed at your exact use case of copying stuff to the output directory.

Also be aware that you can parameterize your build as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471460/setting-maven-params-in-jenkins) (ignore the Jenkins part of that title, the answer relates to general Maven usage).

Answer (score 7):

You could use [this plugin](http://evgeny-goldin.com/wiki/Copy-maven-plugin) in a profile:

```
<pluginRepositories>
  <pluginRepository>
    <id>evgenyg</id>
    <name>Evgeny Goldin repo</name>
    <url>http://evgenyg.artifactoryonline.com/evgenyg/repo/com/github/goldin/</url>
  </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>copy</id>
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>com.github.goldin</groupId>
          <artifactId>copy-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>0.2.5</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>create-archive</id>
              <phase>generate-resources</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>copy</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <resources>
                  <resource>
                    <targetPath>${project.build.outputDirectory}/work/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/</targetPath>
                    <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                    <includes>
                      <include>log4j.xml</include>
                    </includes>
                  </resource>
                </resources>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

To activate: `mvn -Pcopy generate-resources`

Comment: Thanks for the snippet, especially the part about profiles is invaluable. I will probably first try to do what I need with "standard plugins" so to say, without adding any extra 3rd party dependencies if possible.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **copy artifact** plugin. As in hudson.

Comment: Can you give link to maven "copy artifact" plugin, Google did not find one. Or did you mean http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/ instead?

Comment: I am not building and running under hudson/jenkins, I am building and running under NetBeans. In other words, there is no CI job (well, not related to this question), so I have no place to use that plugin.

Comment: This will help you much.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586202/best-practices-for-copying-files-with-maven