# How to make .properties read parameters from Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I use Jenkins to run regression periodically
I have java-maven project with 'ATC.properties' where I can choose browser, environment etc. by uncommenting appropriate one

```
#### browser ######
browser.name=firefox
#browser.name=chrome
#browser.name=ie
```

So I have to commit it, push and only after that job on Jenkins will run build with chosen parameters in 'ATC.properties' as well

How can I make my maven project read parameters from parametrised Jenkins build.
Can any one give me some example with browser ?
Do I have to use another one '.properties' file with described variables 
like

```
browser.name=${browser.name} ...
```

in my project ?

Comment: you can choose one of the 3 solutions in the topic : 
[Stackoverflow][1]

you can choose meven profile solution is the best for me
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9478622/3584773

Answer (score 1):

Parameters defined in Jenkins will be expanded at run in Maven Build , Below process does not require additional property file :

Define jenkins choice parameter :

```
browser_name
```

Provide all your Browsers options as choices and select the required option at run time.

Now replace your pom.xml with `${browser_name}` where you required the option of reading browser value instead of reading value from property file.

pass parameter at run time as below

```
mvn clean install -Dbrowser_name=%browser_name% [incase of windows]
mvn clean install -Dbrowser_name=$browser_name  [incase of linux]
```

Comment: Can you please give more information or some piece of example about 

"Now replace your pom.xml with ${browser_name} where you required the option of reading browser value instead of reading value from property file."

- I want to have possibility locally switch environment by comment - uncomment in ATC.properties and also on independently on Jenkins

Thanks a lot

Comment: i believe you pass browser using ATC,properties files in the property tag of pom.xml , i suggest u to replace that with ${browser_name} , which will expand to the value you selected in jenkins run, and locally when u run you can directly give the value in -Dbrowser_name=chrome , which will do the same thing

Comment: What to do if I don't use any related tag with browser in POM - my code gets this parameter by key from ATC.properties:
    browser.name=firefox
    #browser.name=chrome
    #browser.name=ie
In this case active browser is firefox