# How to choose testcases available in testng.xml to execute from jenkins UI

Tags: selenium, jenkins, testng

I want to run one or more testcases from Jenkins UI which are listed in testng.xml file.

In my testng file there are only three testcases, and I have distributed in different OS and browsers.

Below is the testng.xml code

```
<!-- Chrome_Browser on Mac OS -->

<test name="ChromeMacTestcase1" preserve-order="true">
    <parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />
    <parameter name="version" value="54" />
    <parameter name="platform" value="Mac OS X 10.9" />
    <classes>
        <class name="com.testCases.Testcase1">
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>
<test name="ChromeMacTestcase2"
    preserve-order="true">
    <parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />
    <parameter name="version" value="54" />
    <parameter name="platform" value="Mac OS X 10.9" />
    <classes>
        <class name="com.testCases.Testcase2">
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>

<test name="ChromeMacTestcase3"
    preserve-order="true">
    <parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />
    <parameter name="version" value="54" />
    <parameter name="platform" value="Mac OS X 10.9" />
    <classes>
        <class name="com.testCases.Testcase3">
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>

<!-- Chrome_Browser on Windows OS -->

<test name="ChromeWinTestcase1" preserve-order="true">
    <parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />
    <parameter name="version" value="54" />
    <parameter name="platform" value="Windows 10" />
    <classes>
        <class name="com.testCases.Testcase1">
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>
<test name="ChromeWinTestcase2"
    preserve-order="true">
    <parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />
    <parameter name="version" value="54" />
    <parameter name="platform" value="Windows 10" />
    <classes>
        <class name="com.testCases.Testcase2">
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>

<test name="ChromeWinTestcase3"
    preserve-order="true">
    <parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />
    <parameter name="version" value="54" />
    <parameter name="platform" value="Windows 10" />
    <classes>
        <class name="com.testCases.Testcase3">
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>


<!-- Firfox_Browser on Mac OS -->

<test name="FirefoxMacTestcase1" preserve-order="true">
    <parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />
    <parameter name="version" value="54" />
    <parameter name="platform" value="Mac OS X 10.9" />
    <classes>
        <class name="com.testCases.Testcase1">
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>
<test name="FirefoxMacTestcase2"
    preserve-order="true">
    <parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />
    <parameter name="version" value="54" />
    <parameter name="platform" value="Mac OS X 10.9" />
    <classes>
        <class name="com.testCases.Testcase2">
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>

<test name="FirefoxMacTestcase3"
    preserve-order="true">
    <parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />
    <parameter name="version" value="54" />
    <parameter name="platform" value="Mac OS X 10.9" />
    <classes>
        <class name="com.testCases.Testcase3">
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>


<!-- Firefox_Browser on Windows OS -->

<test name="FirefoxWinTestcase1" preserve-order="true">
    <parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />
    <parameter name="version" value="54" />
    <parameter name="platform" value="Windows 10" />
    <classes>
        <class name="com.testCases.Testcase1">
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>
<test name="FirefoxWinTestcase2"
    preserve-order="true">
    <parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />
    <parameter name="version" value="54" />
    <parameter name="platform" value="Windows 10" />
    <classes>
        <class name="com.testCases.Testcase2">
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>

<test name="FirefoxWinTestcase3"
    preserve-order="true">
    <parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />
    <parameter name="version" value="54" />
    <parameter name="platform" value="Windows 10" />
    <classes>
        <class name="com.testCases.Testcase3">
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>
```

Basically the following things I want to perform from jenkins UI.

- First I want to select Browser and OS.
- Second I want to run all the testcases based on selected browser and OS
- Third I want to run only two testcase(Testcase1 and Testcase2) based on selected browser and OS.

How to pass these parameters from Jenkins to testng.xml and run the testcases as per selected options from Jenkins UI?

Comment: Which build tool you are using ? maven ?

Comment: Yes Ankur, I am using maven build

Comment: Why not just use groups here and then make use of something like a `beanshell` to choose the groups ? You can read more about using the beanshell from [this](https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2013/08/21/beanshell-and-testng/) blog post of mine. Wouldn't that be a lot more easier for you ?

Comment: u can pass parameters through ur Jenkins to ur testng.xml file

Comment: Thanks, Krishnan and Ankur                                                      @AnkurSingh, Are you suggesting the same concept which is suggested by Krishnan Mahadevan?

Comment: My this can help you more refe the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471460/setting-maven-params-in-jenkins?rq=1

Comment: @kamal Did you get the answer for your question ?. To execute specific test case like FirefoxWinTestcase3 ?